# Trying to split mysql_fetch_array into multiple arrays... dont know how to reference column names for keys

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to split a mysql_fetch_array into multiple arrays by matching up the keys in a few predefined arrays to the column names of my mysql query:

```
while ($Row = mysql_fetch_array($Data)){
   if(array_key_exists($k,$CreateClientData)){
       $CreateClientData[$k] = $v;
   }elseif(array_key_exists($k,$CreateRecurringData)){
       $CreateRecurringData[$k] = $v;
   }
}
```

I know how to produce $v... but not $k.  How do i produce the column names inside of this array?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
while ($Row = mysql_fetch_array($Data)){
   foreach($Row as $k => $v){
       // $k = column name
       // $v = column value
       if(array_key_exists($k,$CreateClientData)){
           $CreateClientData[$k] = $v;
       }elseif(array_key_exists($k,$CreateRecurringData)){
           $CreateRecurringData[$k] = $v;
       }
   }
}
```

After execution, `$CreateClientData` will hold the first row's column => value mappings, and `$CreateRecurringData` will hold the last row's column => value mappings.

Supposing `$CreateClientData` and `CreateRecurringData` start as empty arrays, then this can be simplified to:

```
$i = 0;
while($Row = mysql_fetch_array($Data)){
    if($i == 0){
        $CreateClientData = $Row;
    }else{
        $CreateRecurringData = $Row;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Suppose `$CreateClientData` has only a subset of keys you're retrieving from `$Row` (nb: if this is the case, maybe you should retrieve fewer columns from the database), then you can iterate over `$CreateClientData` instead of `$Row`. If `$CreateClientData` has different keys than `$CreateRecurringData`, you can precompute the set union, but again, you're best bet is to select from the database only the columns you need.

Comment: Is it neccessary to have a foreach inside of a while?  I was under the impression that nested loops could be inefficient.

Comment: @rob: it's unclear what the starting and end conditions are, I'm simply populating the missing values of `$k` for you.

Comment: I'm looking for the most efficient way to place the current column name as $k.

Comment: @rob: `$Row` may have many column names, if you want to *iterate* through them, you need a loop. See an update for a far more efficient equivalent answer if some preconditions hold.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't clarify.  The key's in the arrays specified are predefined.  What I'm trying to do is place the value of the current row into the corresponding key.  Basically, column a,b,c belong in this array a, column x,y,z belong in array b.  I don't think your update applies.

Comment: @rob: my answer holds, use the first presented solution.